# App crashes while setting Adapter for simple List View

Tags: android, listview

**Broadcast Receiver in Main Activity**

```
    public class SyncBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //giving a unique action name
    public static final String broadcastAction = "com.dastecsolution.zoos.contentsync.BROADCAST";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("key") + ": " + intent.getStringExtra("value");
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(intent.getAction());

        //Add it to the list or do whatever you wish to

        ListView syncListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.syncLogListView); //it becomes null
        ArrayList<String> bodyarr = new ArrayList<String>();
        bodyarr.add(msg);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, bodyarr);
        try{
            syncListView.setAdapter(arrayAdpt); // null pointer exception here
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
        }

       // Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Layout code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dastecsolution.zoos.SyncActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/LeftSyncMain"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/LeftSyncMenu"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Sync Content"
                android:id="@+id/syncContentBtn"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Sync Images"
                android:id="@+id/syncImagesBtn"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/syncLogLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">
                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/syncLogListView" />    
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log**

```
 12-09 10:53:19.199 14412-14412/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
 12-09 10:53:19.219 14412-14412/com.manish.package D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
 12-09 10:53:19.279 14412-14412/com.manish.package W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
  12-09 10:53:20.099 14412-14412/com.manish.package E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: season_year
12-09 10:53:20.129 14412-14412/com.manish.package I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
12-09 10:53:20.139 14412-14412/com.manish.package D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
12-09 10:53:20.619 14412-14426/com.manish.package W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/storage/emulated/0/DB.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
12-09 10:53:20.619 14412-14426/com.manish.package W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/storage/emulated/0/DB.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
12-09 10:53:21.029 14412-14412/com.manish.package I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-09 10:53:21.149 14412-14412/com.manish.package I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@224b06a7 time:6197910
```

Hi All I am new to android. Unable to find, why my app crashes while setting ListView Adapter. However Toast is working in the same code block.

Also unable to find any errr in log. Want to set this ListView with the sync log through Broadcast receiver

Comment: first clear one thing why you are not getting any error log! inside search box after #Android Monitor , is there any specific #word there already for search? if yes then remove that word from that search box and then pest that error log here ,so we can figure out the exact issue.

Comment: Hi Radhey .. Updated the BroadcastReceiver Code.  syncListView  is setting to null.  ListView syncListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.syncLogListView); //it becomes null

Comment: brother ,want full stack trace or error log from logcat ,update for the same .

Comment: Just declare your #ListView syncListView ,globally at class level ,not inside broadcast receiver ,and take reference like #syncListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.syncLogListView); ,same for the #
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt , and #ArrayList<String> bodyarr ..if still getting error then ping me back.@Manish Kumar

Comment: Not worked.....

Comment: text your entire java file .

Answer (score 0):

A BroadcastReceiver is an Android app component that responds to system-wide broadcast announcements. Imagine an event like external power being connected/disconnected from the device, screen turning on/off, battery getting low or picture captured. All these events originate from the system.

You have to use Activity of Fragment Activity to display the list and set adapter to that list.

http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65